# C# Fill combobox from dataset

Tags: c#, combobox, dataset, filtering, fill

I'm just new to C# and Windows Forms so sorry if I miss something. Currently I use dictionaries as a datasource for my comboboxes. But as I just found out, filtering is not possible with that(?). So it seems better to fill my comboboxes with a dataset/datatables. But how could I do that if I want specific display-member?
Here is my example:
I've a Datatable "players" which contains information about a player. Just like:

```
playerid | lastnameid | firstnameid | birthdate | weight
50000      | 2001       | 2003        | 19940406  | 80
50002      | 2003       | 2001        | 19940423  | 81
```

and a playernames table with

```
nameid | name
2001 | Max 
2003 | Mustermann
```

My ValueMember will be the playerid but how can I display the names instead of the playername-ids?

Comment: ComboBox has a _DisplayMember_ property and this has nothing to do with _filtering_. Also what is the problem with _filling a Dataset_?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to join the datasets and use `DisplayMember`

```
comboBox.DataSource = dataSource;
comboBox.DisplayMember = "name";
comboBox.ValueMember = "playerid";
comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Setting those properties in that order is well know to be the source of performance problems

Comment: @Steve Thanks, I didn't know that. Can you elaborate a little more?